# What's the easiest way to insert a Spark dataframe into Snowflake without duplicate rows?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to create a Spark dataframe and add the values to a Snowflake table. It works, the only problem is I occasionally get duplicate entries.

How can I avoid duplicates?

```
# create DF that will be inserted 
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
  (job_name, run_date)
],  
"job_name string, current_run string"
)

t = sfOptions['sfSchema'] + '.my_snowflake_table'
df.write.format("snowflake").options(**sfOptions).option("dbtable", t).mode("append").save()
```

Based on the allowed modes, I chose append. I definitely don't want overwrite or error. Ignore doesn't write even though the new row doesn't exist in Snowflake (but other rows exist).

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.mode.html

Do I need to try an insert or merge statement?

Comment: The usual way to avoid duplicates is to use MERGE indeed.